# Issue to add custom claim "samaccountname" into azure ad

Tags: azure, authentication, jwt, claims-based-identity

I need to add the custom claim "samAccountName" to be shown in a token (using jwt)

First, I created the powershellscript

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{
                     "ClaimsMappingPolicy": {
                         "Version": 1,
                         "IncludeBasicClaimSet": "true",
                         "ClaimsSchema":[{

                                 "Source": "user",
                                 "ID": "onpremisessamaccountname",
                                 "SamlClaimType": "samaccountname",
                                 "JwtClaimType": "samAccountName"
                             },
  ]
                     }
                 }') -DisplayName "att_ext_samaccountname_even2_prod" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

I assined the new policy to my objectid and its seems to be ok
[image]

In azure manifest I put "acceptMappedClaims": true and it looks like this

[image]

but in "Token confguration -> Optional claims" it looks like this (warning sign)

[image]

And I cannot find the claim to be added when select "add optional claim"

any thoughts of what I'm doing wrong of what is missing?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I modified **acceptedMappedClaims to true** and added the extension in app manifest like below:

[image]

**And got the same error as below:**

[image]

Alternatively, I used below PowerShell commands to add **`samaccountname`** extension in token like below:

```
$MyApp = (New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "AppName").ObjectId  

New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId (Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString "AppName").AppId  

New-AzureADApplicationExtensionProperty -ObjectId $MyApp -Name "samaccountname" -DataType "String" -TargetObjects "User"  

Set-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId ServicePrincipalObjectId -ExtensionName "extension_XXXX_samaccountname" -ExtensionValue "Value"
```

**After executing the above commands, I got the response like below:**

[image]

I was able to add the **`samaccountname`** as an optional claim in the Azure Portal like below:

[image]

After decoding the token (generated using auth code) flow got **`samaccountname`** successfully like below:

[image]

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Azure AD cmdlets to work with extension attributes | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0#create-a-new-extension-property)

[Inlcude onpemise samaccount in azure ad claims by soumi-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/6472/inlcude-onpemise-samaccount-in-azure-ad-claims.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only two things i needed to do was

1: Create a custom policy and map it to the app

```
# Create a new AzureAD Application
$AppName = 'TestApp'
New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $AppName

# Create a new AzureAD Service Principal and store its ObjectId
$ServicePrincipal = New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AppId (Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString $AppName).AppId  

# Create policy and apply to app
$definition = @(
    '{"ClaimsMappingPolicy":{"Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", "ClaimsSchema": [
        {"Source":"user","ID":"onpremisessamaccountname","JwtClaimType":"samaccountname"},
    ]}}'
)
$Policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition $definition -DisplayName "CustomClaimsPolicy-test" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy" -IsOrganizationDefault $false
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $ServicePrincipal.ObjectId -RefObjectId $Policy.Id
```

2: In the manifest set acceptMappedClaims to true

The custom claim created using the policy will not be visible in the manifest nor in the Token configuration GUI but it will be returned in the id_token as "samaccountname" (can be checked using Postman and jwt.io).

There is no need to add an extensionproperty in this manner:

```
New-AzureADApplicationExtensionProperty -ObjectId $MyApp -Name "samaccountname" -DataType "String" -TargetObjects "User"
```

That will create an attribute named something like extension_2fbbba34076a4c79a476b3ge88db1614_samaccountname, it will
be visible in the GUI, but I was unable to get it working so that the user's own samaccountname is returned when the user authenticates. I think this will be a static claim for the application but as of now I'm not completely sure of this.

Comment: The most relevant part of this answer was found here: https://securecloud.blog/2019/06/06/add-samaccountname-to-azure-ad-access-token-jwt-with-claims-mapping-policy-and-avoiding-aadsts50146/