How to add on premise user attributes as claim in token?
I have register an application in Microsoft Entra ID. I have been able to generate jwt token based on the configuration of the application (client_id, tenant_id ...)
I want to add user’s property onpremisessamaccountname in jwt access token generated.

Don't bother the fact here, the value is empty, I have another tenant on which on premise data are synced and filled.
From the Token configuration page of the application, the onpremisessamaccountname is not display in optional claim list.

My question is how can I add this property as a claim in the generated token ?

Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72980955/issue-to-add-custom-claim-samaccountname-into-azure-ad

@Rukmini tried it but not working

Try this script and use user interactive flow to generate tokens https://securecloud.blog/2019/06/06/add-samaccountname-to-azure-ad-access-token-jwt-with-claims-mapping-policy-and-avoiding-aadsts50146/ and check

The AzureADPreview module to install is coming from an untrust repository

So you do want to install AzureADPreview? and AFAIK it is okay to install AzureADPreview module

To add on-premises user attributes as claim in the token you need to add the onPremisesSamAccountname to the claims and send it within the access token by creatin the policy.
Create a new Microsoft Entra Application and create the policy like below:
Connect-AzureAD
 
$Definition = [ordered]@{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy" = [ordered]@{
        "Version" = 1
        "IncludeBasicClaimSet" = $true
        "ClaimsSchema" = @(
            [ordered]@{
                "Source" = "user"
                "ID" = "onpremisessamaccountname"
                "JwtClaimType" = "onpremisessamaccountname"
            }
        )
    }
}
$pol =  New-AzureADPolicy -Definition ($definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3) -DisplayName ("Policy_" + ([System.Guid]::NewGuid().guid) + "_" + $template.Values.claimsschema.JwtClaimType) -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
  
$entApp =  New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName  ("RukClaimsDemoApp_" + $template.Values.claimsschema.JwtClaimType)
$spnob =  New-AzureADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $entApp.DisplayName -AppId $entApp.AppId 
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $spnob.ObjectId -RefObjectId $pol.Id 


Check if the policy is created:
Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id SPNObjectID


In the Manifest, update the acceptMappedClaims as true:

The scope in the Expose an API will be added automatically:

Grant API permissions like below:

For sample, Generated tokens using interactive flow via Postman:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
scope:ClientID/.default openid
client_secret:***


When you decode the tokens, the claim  onpremisessamaccountname will be displayed.

Installing AzureADPreview module will not cause any issue, you can install the module.
Otherwise, refer this MsDoc to create claim mapping policy.

References:
Add sAMAccountName to Azure AD Access Token (JWT) with Claims Mapping Policy (and avoiding AADSTS50146) – SecureCloudBlog
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questi/azure-ad-custom-attribute by Sandeep G-MSFT

Have you tried this code ? Because I'm getting error when executing the second script starting with $pol.
Code: Request_InvalidRequestUrl
Message: Request url was invalid. The request should be like /tenantdomainname/Entity or /$metadata. Tenant domain name can be any of the verified, unverified domain names or context id.```

Yes I was able to run the script successfully

Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/21989/get-azureadpolicy-is-not-working
